# Binding generic type ItemsControl ItemsSource in custom control to DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, dependency-properties

As for question, I've created a custom `UserControl`. It has an `ItemsControl` which `ItemsSource` is binded to a property bindable as `DependecyProperty`.

MyControl XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=InternalControl}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

MyControl Code:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SetInternalControlProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ObservableCollection<dynamic>),
            typeof(ObservableCollection<dynamic>),
            typeof(UtilityExpander));

    public ObservableCollection<dynamic> InternalControl
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<dynamic>)GetValue(SetInternalControlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SetInternalControlProperty, value); }
    }
```

Main XAML:

```
    <Controls:UtilityExpander InternalControl="{Binding GasControl}"/>
```

Main Code:

```
    private ObservableCollection<UtilityGas> _gasControl;
    public ObservableCollection<UtilityGas> GasControl { get => _gasControl; set { _gasControl = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }
```

When running on the `InitializeComponent()` I get

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'InternalControl' property of type 'UtilityExpander'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.'

The reason why I'm using `dynamic` is that I want to use the control with different type of `IEnumerable<objects>`

Comment: Maybe this can help you:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31542/WPF-How-To-Bind-to-Generic-Methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors in the declaration of the dependency property.

The second argument of the Register method must be the name of the property, not that of the property's type. The backing field must be named like the property, with the suffix `Property`.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty InternalControlProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(InternalControl),
        typeof(ObservableCollection<dynamic>),
        typeof(UtilityExpander));

public ObservableCollection<dynamic> InternalControl
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<dynamic>)GetValue(InternalControlProperty); }
    set { SetValue(InternalControlProperty, value); }
}
```

---

Besides that, the property would be more usable if it would be declared as `IEnumerable<dynamic>`. Whether its value implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` or not could be checked at runtime.

The `dynamic` collection type argument seems also redundant. When you declare the property like shown below, you can assign any type of collection, even with different element types in a single collection instance. This is by the way how the `ItemsSource` property is defined.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty InternalControlProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(InternalControl),
        typeof(IEnumerable),
        typeof(UtilityExpander));

public IEnumerable InternalControl
{
    get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(InternalControlProperty); }
    set { SetValue(InternalControlProperty, value); }
}
```

---

Finally, you should also avoid to set the DataContext of your control to itself, because that breaks the standard data binding behaviour of the control's properties, e.g. `InternalControl="{Binding GasControl}"`.

Bind to the own property in the control's XAML with an ElementName or RelativeSource Binding:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=InternalControl,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" >
```

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the first error, yes, I mis-wrote things here. My bad. The second one I missed completely. Plus I had to fix the binding in the Main `InternalControl="{Binding GasControl, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl} }"/>` Now it works perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that you have to fix the Binding in the UtilityExpander's XAML, not where you use the control in e.g. a MainWindow (as explained in the last section of the answer). A control must never set its own DataContext.